# How to Get Rid of Superscript Cite Keys

Tags: bibliographies

My `\cite{key}` usage referring to bibliographies started to do this;

[image: output]

Not only I get a clickable numbered link (which is fine) I get the cite key on top of the reference. How can I turn this off?

I am using pdfTeX 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 through TeXLive on Debian.

Comment: this is probably a consequence of using some (unknown to us) package,  please provide a small compilable example, beginning with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`, so it can be diagnosed without a crystal ball.

Comment: Remove the call to the `showkeys` package.

Comment: Removing showkeys packlage inclusion solved the problem! Thanks @egreg